# Can't boot ubuntu after installing nvidia driver on laptop

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, mount, graphics

The goal is to activate dedicated graphic card to play game.
I updated kernel to install nvidia driver.

I can boot the system in recovery mode but no network available in it.

bellow, this is what i see after reboot after installing nvidia driver. and it does not boot further.

if i purge nvidia via recovery mode, everything gets back to normal(boots properly)

i have lenovo yoga with i7 with integrated and dedicated graphic cards. all time before i used integrated card with no problems on default drivers. But i wanted to play a game that requires more GPU power and i want to activate it. GPU is geforce 1050 mobile.

nothing worked and i updated kernel via ubuntu mainline kernel installer as i found somewhere.

seems like nvidia driver changes mounting setting but i'm not sure.

How to install nvidia properly?

```
8.3389251 IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
0.3309601 sched_clock: Marking stable (324949169, 5919881)->(362378257, -31502807)
8.3313731 registered taskstats version
0.3316921 Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
8.3326311 Loaded X.509 cert "Build time autogenerated kernel key: 8732c115dd832bccb9499572a2159deee14867'
8.3330481 Loaded X.599 cert "Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14d134d1a87c137625abec839ef2b5212496969
0.3334441 Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88752568a1e73731163a466ad7b78a858c19'
8.3334861 blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.589 certificates
0.333536] Loaded X.589 cert
0.3337861 Zswap: loaded using pool Izo/zbud
'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482a2830dBab2ad5a18b7258da9833ddcef8'
B.3348881 Key type fscrypt registered
8.3341221 Kev tupe fscrypt-provisioning registered
8.3346591 Key type encrypted registered
8.334681] AppArmor: AppArmor shal policy hashing enabled
8.3361961 integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
0.336261] integrity: Loaded X,589 cert 'Microsoft Windous Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd98f99e4f9ael7c55af53'
0.3363871 integrity: Loading X.589 certificate: UEF1: db
0.3363491 integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2811: 13adbf4389bd82789c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
0.3363933 integrity: Loading X.589 certificate: UEFI:b
8.9964251 Integrity: Loaded X.509 cert "7KYoga730-15: 9d9ed4dd5c8f379249c64e13725dbed7'
0.337817] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
0.3378471 Loading compiled-in module X.509 certificates
8.338266] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 8732c115dd832bccb9499572a2159deee14867'
B.3383121 ima: Allocated hash algorithm: shal
0.338338] ima: No architecture policies found
B.3383821 evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
B.338487] evm: security.selinux
0.338436] evm: security.SMACK64
0.3384513 evm: security. SMACK64EXEC B.338469] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
8.338493] evm: security. SMACK64MMAP
0.338510] evm: security. apparmor
0.339744] evm: security. ima
0.348968] evm: security.capability
B.342175] evm: HMAC attrs: Bx1
0.3458663 PM:
Magic number: 7:572:182
0.347288] acpi device:41: hash matches
B.348615] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
B.349942] md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
0.351192] md: If you don't use raid, use raid-noautodetect
0.3524831 md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
0.3536191 md: autorun ..
0.354885] md:
... autorun DONE.
0.356312] /dev/root: Can't open blockdev
B.3575461 VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID-be5b2da7-a51e-46dB-9f9f-Scab82dab85f" or unknoun-block(B,B): error -6
B.358895] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
8.3682111 Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknoun-block(®,®)
B.3615473 CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: Suapper/0 Not tainted 6.1.7-060187-generic #282301181200
8.3629581 Harduare name: LENOVO 81CU/LNVNB161216, BIOS 7KCN33H(V1, 14) 12/29/2020
0.3643251 Call Trace:
0.365682] <TASK>
0.3678441
shou_stack+8x4e/0x61
0.368381] dump_stack_1v1+8x4a/Bx6f
0.3697141 dump_stack+8x10/8x18
0.371069] panic+0x16e/9×31f
0.372375] mount_block_root+8x151/8x1f6
0.373681]
mount_root+0×94/Bxa3
0.375010] prepare_namespace+0×13f/8×181
0.3762961
kernel_init_freeable+Bx11e/0x137
0.3775563
? rest_init+8x180/8x100
0.3788691 kernel_-init+8x1b/Bx170
0.3801161 ? rest_init+8x108/0x100
0.381346] ret_from_fork+0x1f/Bx30
0.3826851
</TASK>
9.3838591 Kernel Offset: 8x19880000 from Bxffffffff81000000 (relocatlon range: Bxffffffffe000000-Bxffffffffbfffffff)
0.3852291
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS; Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Comment: edited, thank you

Comment: I guessed that the GeForce card is not active based on dps in the game. Because I played before and fps should be much higher and laptop usually gets very hot in this game but it's not the case now

Comment: Current kernel 6.1.7 and everything works fine until I install nvidia, I am easily go back to normal behavior on this kernel by purging nvidia.

Comment: I agree, but how to activate the GeForce properly?

Comment: At the same time on default kernel 5.1.5 it was just freezing upon boot and didn't allow to reverse back this easy as 6.1.7

Comment: If we assume that Linux driver was working properly with nvidia, can I force it to use GeForce as default GPU instead of the one front Intel?

Comment: I didn't use nvidia on Linux, I used it on windows a couple month ego and desided to switch to Linux

Comment: Only performance what I need. And the game doesn't seem to be only for windows.

Comment: No Ubuntu product or release details were provided, are we to guess?  You've also given no clues in your question about what change(s) you made, only indications that after reversion the system restored to operation.  All details about your problem belong in your question